# Разница между делегированием и композицией?

Tags: java

Какая разница между делегированием и композицией?
-Делегирование когда в классе создается экземпляр другого класса, и вызываются методы?

```
public class A{  
    int  a;   
    void b(){}   
}

class B{   
    B() {
        A a = new A();   
        a.b();   
    }    
}
```

-Композиция - это когда в одном классе создается экземпляр другого и  динамически могут меняться поля в экземпляре другого класса?

```
public class A{     
    int a=5;     
    void b(){}    
}

class B{   
    B(){  
        A a = new A();     
        a.a=10; 
    }     
}
```

Comment: отформатируйте пожалуйста код. Не надо выкладывать это в таком виде

Comment: как сделать чтобы код картинкой выделялся?

Comment: что значит "чтобы код картинкой выделялся"?

Comment: чтобы подсвечивался, как в примере "class B{"

Comment: выделите код и нажмите кнопку {}

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Это разные понятия.

*Делегирование* - это когда часть работы класс **"перекладывает на"** другие классы.

Например, начальник разработки, получив заказ на новую фичу, **делегирует** эту задачу одному из своих подчиненных.

Пример делегирования в программировании - когда класс, выполняющий сложный алгоритм логирует свои действия не самостоятельно (открывая файл и дописывая в него), а **с помощью** класса `Logger`, вызывая в нужных местах его методы.

Обычно *делегированию* противопоставляют реализацию чего-либо в том же классе. Например, если у вас есть класс-"всемогутор", то лучше разделить его на несколько классов, у каждого из которых будет своя зона ответственности. Основной класс будет лишь заниматься диспетчеризацией вызовов между этими классами.

Посмотрите [статью в Wiki](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

*Композиция* - это когда между моделируемыми объектами явно прослеживается отношение **"часть - целое"** (has a).

Например, моделируя автомобиль, естественно считать, что двигатель - это **часть** автомобиля. Программируя эту модель, Вы выразите это в том, что объект класса `Engine` **станет членом класса** `Auto`.

*Композиции* обычно противопоставляют агрегацию и ассоциацию. *Агрегация* похожа на композицию в том, что это тоже отношение вида **часть-целое**, однако между объектами **нет отношения владения**. Например, "группа студентов" - студент часть группы, но студент может существовать и вне группы. То есть деструктор группы не должен "убивать" объектов-студентов.
*Ассоциация* выражает любое отношение между объектами, которые могут вызывать методы друг друга.

То есть делегирование можно устроить имея как отношение *ассоциации*, так и отношение *композиции* между объектами.

Еще *композиции* противопоставляют наследование. Но в этом случае *композиция* и *делегирование* - синонимы. В случае с наследованием мы выносим общие методы в базовый класс `Base`, а различные реализации в классы-наследники `Derived1`, `Derived2`. Создавая экземпляр одного из `Derived`-классов, мы получаем необходимую функциональность объекта.

Но то же самое можно сделать и по-другому. В классе `Base` мы по-прежнему оставляем общие методы, и **добавляем ссылку (указатель)** (то есть аггрегируем указатель на реализацию) на интерфейс вспомогательных методов `IRealization`. Вспомогательные методы по-разному реализуются в классах `Realization1`, `Realization2`, которые наследуют* интерфейс `IRealization`. Теперь в зависимости от того, на объект какого из классов `Realization` будет указывать объект `Base`, мы будем получать разную функциональность. `Base` делегирует свои обязаности в `IRealization`.

PS. по поводу последнего абзаца была хорошая статья на Хабре, но я её не нашел. Поэтому отправляю Вас к первоисточнику той статьи -  [книга по Паттернам проектирования Фримена](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/6108824/)

Comment: +1, хорошее объяснение.

Answer (score 6):

пожалуй проще всего обьяснить на таком примере:

```
// интерфейс который который будет использоватся для примеров
interface ITestable
{
    public void test () ;
}

// его реализация
class A implements ITestable
{
    public void test ()
    {
        System.out.println ( "do test a" ) ;
    }
}

class Composition
{
    private ITestable testable ;

    public ITestable getTestable ()
    {
        return testable ;
    }

    public void setTestable ( ITestable testable )
    {
        this.testable = testable ;
    }
}

class DelegationA implements ITestable
{
    private ITestable testable ;

    public DelegationA ( ITestable testable )
    {
        this.testable = testable ;
    }

    public void test ()
    {
        System.out.println ( "delegating test to: " + testable.getClass () ) ;
        testable.test () ;
    }
}

class DelegationB implements ITestable
{
    private ITestable testable ;

    public DelegationB ( ITestable testable )
    {
        this.testable = testable ;
    }

    public void test ()
    {
        System.out.println ( "before test" ) ;
        testable.test () ;
        System.out.println ( "after test" ) ;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void main ( String [] args )
    {
        A a = new A ();

        // initialize composition
        Composition c = new Composition ();
        c.setTestable ( a );

        // test of composition class
        System.out.println ("---------------------") ;
        System.out.println ("testing composition: ") ;
        c.getTestable ().test (); 
        /* ^^ we know composition class have testeble, 
         * so we are using it to perform some actions
         * Example: System.out.println();  out is an nested field, and is example of composition  
         */

        // adjust behavior using different delegations
        DelegationA d1 = new DelegationA ( a ); 
        DelegationB d2 = new DelegationB ( a );
        DelegationA d3 = new DelegationA ( d1 );
        DelegationA d4 = new DelegationA ( d2 );

        // test of delegation
        System.out.println ("---------------------") ;
        System.out.println ("testing delegation: ") ;
        ITestable [] arr = new ITestable[] {a, d1, d2, d3, d4};
        for ( ITestable t : arr )
        {
            t.test ();
            System.out.println ("\n") ;
        }
    }
}
```

Композиция это когда сложный класс делают из более мелких частей (составляют). А делегирование это когда композиция используется для того чтобы часть своих обязаностей передать другому классу.

Answer (score 3):

Композиция (наряду с наследованием) - это способ формирования поведения некоторого класса.
Делегирование - это способ определения ответственности за некоторое поведение.

В случае с наследованием, ответственноть делегируется базовому и/или производному классу. В случае с композицией - ответственность делегируется агрегированным классам (включенным в состав вашего класса на этапе инстанциирования). Другими способами делегирования являются например аспекты.

Т.е. более лаконичным ответом на ваш вопрос будет: Композиция - это способ обеспечения делегирования ответственности за поведение (функциональность). Альтернативами композиции являются наследование, аспекты и примеси.

Примером делегирования через композицию является шаблон проектирования "Стратегия", а примером реализации является класс TreeMap, конструктор которого принимает в качестве параметра Comparator, делегируя тем самым ему ответственность за сортировку элементов.